# mysql xa transaction: what this error mean:The command cannot be executed when global transaction is in the IDLE state

Tags: mysql, jboss, transactions, wildfly

After our app is switched from eap 6.0 to wildfly 8.1.0.Final, we keep getting this error.

javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.

```
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1178) [narayana-jts-jacorb-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final (revision: 9aa71)]

at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126) [narayana-jts-jacorb-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final (revision: 9aa71)]

at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)

at com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorBase.endTransaction(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:147) [narayana-jts-jacorb-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final (revision: 9aa71)]

at com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:93) [narayana-jts-jacorb-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final (revision: 9aa71)]

at com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:52) [narayana-jts-jacorb-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final (revision: 9aa71)]

at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor203.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0]

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0]

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0]

at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.SimpleMethodInvocation.invoke(SimpleMethodInvocation.java:30) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]

at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.chain.AbstractInterceptionChain.invokeNext(AbstractInterceptionChain.java:103) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]

at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.chain.AbstractInterceptionChain.invokeNextInterceptor(AbstractInterceptionChain.java:81) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]

at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeInterception(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:48) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]

at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.invoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:41) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]

at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:53) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]

at com.pearson.epen.impl.service.auth.RestAuthServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.authCheck(Unknown Source) [epen-common-1.5.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:]

at com.pearson.epen.impl.service.auth.RestAuthServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.authCheck(Unknown Source) [epen-common-1.5.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:]

at com.pearson.epen.tools.servlet.filter.EpenAuthFilter.execute(EpenAuthFilter.java:149) [epen-common-1.5.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:]

at com.pearson.epen.tools.servlet.filter.AbstractHttpServletRequestFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpServletRequestFilter.java:27) [epen-common-1.5.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:]

at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]

at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)

at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]

at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]

at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]

at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]

at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]

at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]

at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)

at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]

at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]

at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]

at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0]

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0]

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
```

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement

```
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]

at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]

at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]

at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$CallbackExceptionMapperImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1882) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]

at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:115) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]

at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:50) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]

at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76) [narayana-jts-jacorb-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final (revision: 9aa71)]

at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:358) [narayana-jts-jacorb-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final (revision: 9aa71)]

at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:91) [narayana-jts-jacorb-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final (revision: 9aa71)]

at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162) [narayana-jts-jacorb-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final (revision: 9aa71)]

at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1166) [narayana-jts-jacorb-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final (revision: 9aa71)]

... 46 more
```

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement

```
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]

at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]

at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]

at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:190) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]

at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3285) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]

at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3183) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]

at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3525) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]

at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:159) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]

at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]

at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]

at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]

at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]

at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]

at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]

at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:110) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]

... 52 more
```

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: XAER_RMFAIL: The command cannot be executed when global transaction is in the  IDLE state

```
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1086)

at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)

at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)

at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617)

at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)

at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2834)

at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2156)

at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2441)

at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2366)

at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2350)

at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.PreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:875)

at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.CachedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(CachedPreparedStatement.java:119)

at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:493)

at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:187) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
```

What does this error mean?

Our example datasource config is like this:

```
                <xa-datasource-property name="URL">

                    jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/xxxx?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci&amp;characterSetResults=utf8&amp;characterEncoding=utf8

                </xa-datasource-property>

                <driver>com.mysql</driver>

                <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>

                <xa-pool>

                    <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>

                    <max-pool-size>50</max-pool-size>

                    <prefill>true</prefill>

                    <use-strict-min>true</use-strict-min>

                    <flush-strategy>IdleConnections</flush-strategy>

                    <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>

                    <pad-xid>false</pad-xid>

                    <wrap-xa-resource>true</wrap-xa-resource>

                </xa-pool>

                <security>

                    <user-name>xxxx</user-name>

                    <password>xxxx</password>

                </security>

                <validation>

                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.novendor.JDBC4ValidConnectionChecker"/>

                    <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>

                    <use-fast-fail>true</use-fast-fail>

                    <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.StaleConnectionChecker"/>

                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>

                </validation>

                <statement>

                    <track-statements>TRUE</track-statements>

                    <prepared-statement-cache-size>100</prepared-statement-cache-size>

                    <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>

                </statement>

            </xa-datasource>

Some forums say that setting the pinGlobalTxToPhysicalConnection property to true in datasource config will fix this problem.  But what is the corresponding attribute in wildfly datasource configuraton? I could not find pinGlobalTxToPhysicalConnection in the mysql datasource config.



It could be the problem was that for the same transaction, the same datasource get called multiple times. Mysql might not like this. Or it could be when the connection is being closed, some things happens.



Either way we did not see this error when we were using jboss eap 6. This implies that the jca or resource manager change in wildfly are trigger this issue. Or it could be jboss eap's jca impl hid the problem.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can either prepare or issue a commit using a commit one phase statement.

Comment: Do you mind elaborate more? Example would be great. We use jpa in wildfly/jboss. Transaction is managed by container.